# How to know when sentence of text end in Unity using c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using Unity3D with C#. Well, I have a dialogue text script with a foreach that run the sentences list, I need to know how I can know when the first sentence finishes.

Here is my code :

```
public void StartDialogue(Dialogue dialogue)
{
    //Debug.Log("Start conversation with " + dialogue.name);
    cameradialogue.SetActive(true);
    FindObjectOfType<ThirdPersonCharacter> ().isStop = true;
    DialogueBox.SetActive (true);
    NameText.text = dialogue.name;
    sentences.Clear();
    foreach (string sentence in dialogue.sentences)
        sentences.Enqueue (sentence);
    DisplayNextSentence();
}
```

Here my method for display my setences:

```
    IEnumerator TypeSentence (string sentence){
        dialogueText.text = "";
        foreach (char letter in sentence.ToCharArray()) {
            dialogueText.text += letter;
            yield return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well, how are you displaying your sentences? Word by word? Letter by letter? At present it's not very clear what you want to do based on the implementation you've supplied.

Comment: @Serlite I edit the post with the method for display my sentences.

Comment: You need to update your question to make it more clear, like example When do you call `TypeSentence` ? post the script that are related,

Comment: you'll know when the sentence finishes displaying when the `foreach` loop in `TypeSentence` exits..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the foreach loop will finish in the TypeSentence method, It will mean that the complete sentence has been displayed in the dialog text.